# How would I make a discord bot store messages from DMs but only once they have done a command in a server

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I am making a discord bot (written in python) that handles applications. What you're meant to do is do `$apply` in a discord server, then the bot would send you questions 1 by 1 in DMs. The bot will store all of the answers, then send them into a private channel in the discord server.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a dictionary of all users, keyed on the user's ID with the value being a bool set to true if they have sent the command and false if they haven't. After that it's simply setting the value anytime the command is called and then checking the value whenever you want to store the messages for a user.